# To what value does the sum of the areas of the dark triangles converge if the area of ​the square is 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, area

To what value does the sum of the areas of the dark triangles converge if the area of ​​the square is 1?

I already calculated the first to layers of triangles and got that one is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the other is $\frac{1}{2^5}$, but I don't see a sequence between those areas.

[image]

Comment: This clearly looks like an infinite series related to a geometric series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the total black area you have  $$\frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{8}+\frac {1}{32}+..... =\frac {1/2}{1-1/4}= \frac {2}{3} $$

Answer (score 1):

The black area in the first "ring" (big square minus second big square) is twice that of the white. This remains valid throughout